# Is it possible to make meta description and keywords from Mysql row data

Tags: php, mysql, tags, meta

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php $row['data_from_input_field'] ?>">
```

I've try something like this but nothing. I have two tables in database. Right now structure is not important. I would like to make keywords of one row from Table 1 and row from Table2.
Is it possible>

Comment: You'd need to [`echo`](http://www.php.net/echo) it, if anything.

Comment: you forgot echo, content="<?php echo $row['data_from_input_field'] ?>

you goal can be achieved easily. Fetch data in a way you want and echo here

Answer (score 1):

Basically two choices:

Optimal: Process to escape quotes, and < > with `&quot;`, `&gt;` and `&lt;`, and any other other stuff you may want to do before commiting to db then use:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?= $row['data_from_input_field'] ?>">
<meta name="description" content=<?= $row['data_from_input_field'] ?>">
```

or do the same after; for example

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?= process_keywords($row['data_from_input_field']) ?>">
<meta name="description" content=<?= process_description($row['data_from_input_field']) ?>">
```

where process_* escapes and does any other changes you want at runtime and then returns the value you want.

Comment: Yes, no any errors. Just when i put <?php= it give me some error, and when remove php from <?= its ok...

Comment: yes `<?=` is valid PHP (basically short for `<?php echo`) where as `<?php=` is not valid PHP